# How to do date calculations in org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to enter a date (as active or inactive timestamps) in column 1 ( eg [2020-02-02 Sun] ) and a number of days in column 2 ( eg as 5d for 5 days) and then let something like:

```
#+TBLFM: $3=$1+$2
```

calculate the resulting date after adding the days of column 2 to the date in column one. What I get as a result in column 3 is

```
 [2020-02-02 Sun] + 5 d
```

Any idea how I can get instead someting like

```
[2020-02-07 Fri]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found my mistake. Just putting 5 instead of 5d into column 2 does the trick. Please delete my question if you like.